# SSMA/SQL Server: Need to alter or backup from GoDaddy

Tags: sql-server, ssms

So I have a site hosted on GoDaddy (not my call...) that I'm working on an upgrade that required simply adding a column in a table. Did it locally, tested and worked like a charm.  Connected to the remote DB and found I couldn't add a column.  Called and after a lot of back and forth, I was told that they don't allow modifications to a db after it's created.  Ummmmmmmm... okay, can I run an alter script?  No...

OK, I'm not a dba so we're rapidly exceeding my comfort level but I thought I'd run a backup, restore it locally, make the modification, back that up and restore it on the host.  Apparently I can't run backup from SSMS on their server.  So I tried their backup tool from their control panel and it gives me a .txt file which doesn't appear to be a backup at all.

Just now I tried scripting the entire db and that isn't looking good either... throwing some kind of error as well.

What the heck else can I do to either make the changes I need or get my data the hell off there and tell my user that we simply MUST change hosts?

Comment: Hook up a Navicat like program remotely and run a backup in that software.

Comment: @juanvan Is that going to do something that SSMS won't do?

Comment: You can run a backup but you can't run an ALTER? Maybe after you do your backup you need to download it using this method: https://au.godaddy.com/help/download-files-8382

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid you can only run a "backup" using their tool apparently.  And it isn't clear to me that the backup is in fact a backup.  I think I was finally successful scripting the entire db, running that locally and making my changes.  In a best case it's going to be an amazing PITA... I'm really astonished.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little late..

One thing you could do from MSSMS...
Right click on your Database  select `Tasks->Generate Scripts.`
Select a location on your PC.

Under `Set Script Options` click `Advanced`.
Change the option `Types of data to script` to `Schema and Data`. Then generate your script

Its not the best case scenario...but its better then nothing.

As for not being able to ALTER the Table...I would most definitely check the use rights of the user your logging in with. I am able to make changes to GoDaddy tables.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of backup, you can try *Extract data tier application* from the database, which generates a *bacpac* file (containing schema and data) and Deploy this *bacpac* locally. 
Make schema changes to this database and take backup of the same and restore in GoDaddy.

More information on [extracting data tier application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/extract-a-dac-from-a-database?view=sql-server-2017)